# google signin force password prompt

Tags: google-openid, google-openidconnect

Google deprecated the use of embedded webviews for authentication with Google Signin in devices like iOS and Android.

Android supports Kiosk mode.  The concept of having numerous users share a single android device is not foreign.  iOS is also frequently used in a "shared device" model.

However, the current implementation of Google Signin for iOS uses SFSafariViewController, which in turn uses system wide shared cookies.  And this is where Google now stores all Google Signin information.  An App can have no control whatsoever over this.  Apple has stated this firmly.

So in Kiosk mode, if an app were to use Google SignIn, there is no "signout", not really.  Each account used will use the same device wide browser cache for tokens... and any other user can then login as that user , within the token expiry period, without a password.  Google will NOT prompt for passwords the 2nd time unless the user has explicitly signed out of their google account in Safari... which is not something the app can manage or control.

So the question is:

How can a developer ensure that when a user signs out of the app they signed in with using Google Signin they will be prompted for a password the next time they sign in?

(research suggests that apparently... they can't, but Google also closed down the forum for comments on this lovely stack claiming they would rather scan Stackoverflow then interact with the foolish gamblers that opt to use their APIs - leaving us to shift our focus to supporting AzureAD instead, which unlike google, does not seem to take such pride in making needless work for developers)

Google Signin is now a mess. No choice to but to toss it.

I hope someone proves me wrong with a clever answer as I would happily reverse my position :)

In this brave new world of continuous improvement... Everything is broken.

Comment: Google donated the code for AppAuth to OpenID foundation and it is at: https://github.com/openid/

Comment: Call the "revocation_endpoint" which is at: https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration